# Passing file contents vs file name with commands

Tags: linux

I have a program that normally takes a file name as input for a file to read from but instead, for scripting purposes , I want to pass the file contents as a parameter.  I cannot re write the program to read the text from command line.  Is there a way to pass the contents as text via command line?  The file is a binary file.

Ex:   prog  file.txt -p 0

Comment: Just for future reference, there is a [unix specific stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site that is great for asking shell and scripting type questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `bash` you can use the so called *process substitution* feature (`<()`), e.g.:

```
prog <(echo $SOME_DATA) -p 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it on linux:

```
$ cat $SOME_DATA | prog /dev/stdin -p 0
```

in this case you're squirting the data into STDIN for `prog`, and then reading from STDIN via the special device `/dev/stdin`.  Note that `/dev/fd/1` is equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure these other answers are correct or will work.

Standard is to use `-` to represent STDIN. When you program parses your ARGV arguments and tries to open the file, then it will map to the STDIN file handle.

```
cat $SOME_DATA | prog -p 0 -
```

Comment: The `-` is not something standard, just a convention for programs able to read from STDIN to not read from file but from STDIN instead. So, using `-` totally depends on whether `prog` understand what `-` means.